# Por que meu "TextAppearence" e meu "TextColor" não funciona em alguns dispositivos Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, background-color

Estou desenvolvendo um app e obviamente ele contém muitos textViews. Eu notei que ao instalar meu app em alguns dispositivos, mais especificamente no MOTO G2, notei que meu textViews ficam estranhos e não apresenta o layout esperado.

Para melhor entendimento, veja um exemplo do código que fiz para um textView no xml.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtExemplo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/azul"
 android:textAppearence="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
    android:text="Exemplo TextView"/>
```

Ou seja, eu defino um Estilo e uma cor, mas especificamente no Moto g2 essas propriedades não se aplicam. Mas por que disso?

Eu não tenho uma imagem para mostrar como fica o resultado, mas vou tentar descrever:

Fica com uma borda preta e o prenchimento interno é branco. Como se ficasse oco.

Answer (score 2):

O problema pode está no sistema operacional do dispositivo. Isto porque, o dispositivo **MOTO G2** possuí uma funcionalidade de cadastramento de usuários para interação com o sistema, assim como nos PCs com o Windows instalado que permite configurar um usuário específico para mexer no computador. O problema está justamente aí pois quando estou no usuário "proprietário" o problema de renderização das cores e estilos ocorre, mas quando entro em outra conta cadastrada, o problema desaparece. Eu observei que não é somente no meu aplicativo que isto está acontecendo e sim com qualquer outro instalado. Em conclusão, afirmo que o problema é justamente no sistema operacional do android mas não sei do porquê que disto. Como não há nada de errado no meu app, não vou me aprofundar no assunto, mas se alguém souber, então deixe um cometário.

Comment: Também há, em acessibilidade, uma opção de _"Texto em alto contraste"_ que adiciona bordas pretas ao texto, não posso confirmar se substitui as cores

Answer (score 0):

Esse `@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline` fica diferente dependendo da versão do Android e dispositivo. Recomendo criar seus próprios estilos.
Cheque a documentação aqui https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes

Comment: Não está funcionando amigo. Eu verifiquei que o problema acontece justamente no "textColor". Eu não entendo porque mas no moto g2 de api 23 não renderiza corretamente a cor.

Comment: Mais obrigado pela a sua opinião;

Comment: Mesmo você removendo o atributo de style continua ficando diferente ?

Comment: Sim.... Mas eu consegui resolver o problema em parte. Deixa eu explicar melhor: O dispositivo moto  G2 possuí uma funcionalidade de cadastramento de usuários para interação com o sistema, assim como nos PCs com o Windows instalado que permite configurar um usuário específico. O problema está justamente aí... Quando eu estou no usuário "prioritário" este problema ocorre, mas quando entro com outro usuário, estranhamente o problema é corrigido. Eu acredito então que o problema está no sistema operacional android do dispositivo.

Comment: prioritário não.... eu quis dizer proprietário.